# Accessing Webapi on Localhost on Dev Machine from Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

This may well be a duplicate question, but no answer from an existing question has solved my problem.

I have a WebAPI end point running on my dev machine. I've configured it to run on

```
.UseUrls("http://localhost:57971", "http://10.0.2.2:57971", "http://192.168.44.1:57971", "http://192.168.1.48:57971", "http://*:57971")
```

where:

**192.168.44.1** is Desktop Adapter #2 on the emulator Networks settings tab

**10.0.2.2** is the special address for the Android emulator, as set out in Google's doco (possibly not relevant to Xamarin) and

**192.168.1.48** is my local IP address for my dev machine.

I have created a firewall rule permitting connections on TCP port 57971.

I researched this pretty heavily and heeded instructions such as those set out here http://briannoyesblog.azurewebsites.net/2016/03/06/calling-localhost-web-apis-from-visual-studio-android-emulator/

I'm kinda out of ideas. The annoying thing is, it fails silently. There is no exception and the output just basically shows the different threads exiting with code 0. And the application keeps running i.e. the debugging session is not returning the IDE to a *"code entry"* state.  This may suggest that something else its at play here.

The code looks pretty innocuous to me:

```
    protected async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url)
        where T : new()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = CreateHttpClient();
        T result;

        try
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
            result = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response));
        }
        catch
        {
            result = new T();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.
I'm using the Visual Studio emulator https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/

Any idea how I can get *wheels on the ground* on this thing?

Is there a way to Ping my machine from the emulator?

Thanks

Comment: Any idea what line it goes rouge? Are you awaiting `GetAsync()`? I would suggest removing the `Task.Run()`, if you are already awaiting `GetAsync()` then it should be on a background thread already.

Comment: @hvaughan3 Thanks for your suggestion. It looks like the call to GetStringAsync is returning null. This begs the question - why? That end-point does return json, when I hit it with Fiddler or a browser.

Comment: Maybe try adding to Debug.WriteLine() statements to see what `response` is before you attempt to deserialize it and what `result` is afterwards. Usually I use `HttpResponseMessage response = HttpClient.SendAsync()` and then you would do `result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());` (obviously you would want to do much more error/null checks).

Comment: @hvaughan3 I took your advice but it is as if those Debug statements don't even get hit. Nothing gets written to output.

Comment: Did you try replacing localhost with your computers name?  The webapi is not running on the emulator it is running on your computer

Comment: @KenTucker Yes. I did not use localhost at all. But I used the IP address of Desktop Adapter #2, not the name of my machine.

Comment: try the machine name instead of the IP

Comment: I got this working by using 169.254.80.80 i.e. I added it to the list of urls which the API serves and called that ip address from the Xamarin app. I also, for good measure, added it to the ApplicationConfig file in the vs folder of the API solution. Not sure why it had to be 169.254.80.80, as that was Desktop Adapter #4. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using 169.254.80.80 i.e. I added it to the list of urls which the API serves and called that ip address from the Xamarin app.

So, in Program.cs became simple:

```
.UseUrls("http://localhost:57971", "http://169.254.80.80:57971")
```

I also had to add it to the *bindings* element **ApplicationConfig** file in the hidden *.vs* folder of the ASP.NET API solution. Not sure why it had to be 169.254.80.80, as that was Desktop Adapter #4.

That got it working.